# C#. Deserialization into same types depending on attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I had been working with deserialization and got stucked.

There is my classes:

```
public class Parent
{
   public List<Child> child {get;set}
}

public class Child
{
   some properties
}

public class Child1 : Child
{
   some properties
}

public class Child2 : Child
{
   some properties
}
```

And I have xml:

```
<Parent>
   <Child AttribName="TypeOne">
   </Child>
   <Child AttribName="TypeTwo">
   </Child>
</Parent>
```

How can I use some [Xml] attributes to do this?
I need `List<Child>` (Child1 or Child2, depending on attrute **AttribName**) in **Parent**

Comment: Is the xml required to appear in this format? Or do you have the flexibility to dictate what it should look like?

Comment: as a side note: part of the *reason* that this is not a supported scenario is that *xsd* doesn't support this

Comment: - Xml reqired this format

Comment: - I need use attributes. Constructions like `[XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Child1)),
        XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Child2))]` or `[XmlElement("Child", Type = typeof(Child1))]
        [XmlElement("Child", Type = typeof(Child2))]` not needed

Comment: @snowil those **are** attributes... do you mean xml attrbutes? or c#? If you mean xml attributes: you're out of luck - `XmlSerializer` *does not support* xml attributes as discriminators

Comment: @MarcGravell, yes exactly, xml attributes

Comment: @snowil: You will have to implement custom serialization then.

Comment: MarcGravell and Juan Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom xml reader like this:

```
public class CustomXmlReader : XmlTextReader
{
    public CustomXmlReader(string url) : base(url) { }

    public override string GetAttribute(string localName, string namespaceURI)
    {
        if (namespaceURI == "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" && localName == "type")
        {
            if (base.LocalName == "Child")
            {
                var attr = base.GetAttribute("AttribName");

                if (attr == "TypeOne")
                    return "Child1";
                if (attr == "TypeTwo")
                    return "Child2";
            }
        }
        return base.GetAttribute(localName, namespaceURI);
    }
}
```

Add attributes to base class:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Child1))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Child2))]
public class Child
```

Example usage:

```
var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parent));

Parent parent;

using (var xmlReader = new CustomXmlReader("test.xml"))
    parent = (Parent)xs.Deserialize(xmlReader);
```

Answer (score 1):

`XmlSerializer` does not support discriminators based on an attribute; only the element name. So you could use `XmlSerializer` for *this* - but not your scenario:

```
<Parent>
   <ChildTypeOne>
   </ChildTypeOne>
   <ChildTypeTwo>
   </ChildTypeTwo>
</Parent>
```

Options:

- deserialize it manually
- transform the xml before deserialization
- simply change the xml format

Comment: I have strong and big xml structure. Transform before serialization will be very heavy operation. Seems I need write custom serializtion. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case with strong xml format and very big files I have just one solution - custom serialization.