How to deserialize XML with different element names?
I want to deserialize many xmls to c# object but xml`s has different names of the same element.
    private FileAsXML GetDataObject(string xml)
    {
        FileAsXML data = new FileAsXML();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FileAsXML));

        serializer.UnknownElement += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Unknown element found: {e.Element.Name}");
        };

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            data = (FileAsXML)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
        return data;
    }

For exmaple i have first xml:
<MainFile>
 <11Test>
  <1Name>Anthony</1Name>
  <HelloFriend11>...</HelloFriend11>
 </11Test>
</MainFile>

Second xml:
<MainFile>
 <11Test11>
  <Name1>Anthony</Name1>
  <1HelloFriend>...</1HelloFriend>
 </11Test11>
</MainFile>

My FileAsXML object:
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "MainFile", IsNullable = true)]
public class FileAsXML
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Test", IsNullable = true)]
    public Test Test{ get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Test", IsNullable = true)]
public class Test
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name", IsNullable = true)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "HelloFriend", IsNullable = true)]
    public HelloFriend HelloFriend{ get; set; }
    
}

Structure of all xml`s are the same but is different elements name but always elements has const part of name.
All of them has "Test" in the element name. How to call XmlSerializer to catch element?
In my object I try different solutions like:
[XmlElement(ElementName = "test", IsNullable = true)]
public string test { get; set; }

or
[XmlAnyElement(Name= "Test"]
public string test { get; set; }

or
[XmlElement(ElementName = "*Test*", IsNullable = true)]
public string test { get; set; }

I have many of element it can be also an object neeeded to serialize.
Maybe someone know solution?
SOLUTION
This approach seems to be wrong. For my case I should use "xml linq c#
Thanks @dbc @user246821 @Alexander Petrov

You can use custom xml reader like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46834791/5045688. Provide more info with XML sample and I'll can write code.

Will there be only one attribute with a name matching the pattern *Test*?  Or could there be multiple attributes?

@AlexanderPetrov
I dont know how i can use in my sytuation.
For example my first xml is like <11Test>value</11Test>. And another <11Test11>value</11Test11>

@dbc exacly, only one attribute with a name matching the pattern *Test*.
But I also trying [XmlElement(ElementName = "*test*", IsNullable = true)] and this doesn`t work

Provide more info. Don't write in the comments. Edit the question body. Also, do not confuse xml elements and attributes - they are completely different things!

Your question title and introductory paragraph mentions "attribute".  In your XML sample <11Test11>value</11Test11> the 11Test11 names are elements.  Elements and attributes are not the same thing, see XML Elements vs. Attributes.  Which is it?  And if an element, is it the root element?  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing XML you need to deserialize.

@dbc Both of you has truth, I was mistake elements with attributes. I need find elements. sorry

OK, but is the varying element name the root element?  The name of a single element?  Or the name of a sequence of elements?  Please share a full [mcve] including the root element and the class to which you want to bind it.  Also, do you need to re-serialize using the original name, or re-serialize with a fixed name <Test>?  Thanks!

@dbc In my sytuation everything you mentioned. Becouse it is a big xmls and I want to create universal c# object.
I was finding solution for one and I was think that will be good for all

It is a big xmls and I want to create universal c# object. -- then don't deserialize to a C# object.  Load to a LINQ-to-XML XElement as shown in this answer to Deserialize arbitrary XML.  XmlSerializer is for deserializing XML that has a fixed schema.  Anyway, creating a universal c# object is completely outside the original intent of your question.

@AlexanderPetrov i was fixing my question.

@dbc But structure of xml files are always the same. Only names of elements change but always has constant part.

If any element name could vary including the root element name, from the point of view of the W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) (which is what XmlSerializer is designed to support) that's basically free-form XML.  But if the root element name is fixed as MainFile and a single property has a varying name, then that can be handled with XmlSerializer.  So is the root fixed, or not?

@dbc I again update my questionfor detail for details :)
Roots inside MainFile can also be different but always have const part.

What do you mean by "roots inside MainFile"?  An XML document has one and only one root element, it's the single element at the beginning of the file that contains all the file's other elements and text content.

@dbc My mistake. MainFile is always const. Never change.
I was thinking that i can also call my Test object as root. I havent experienced in xml. sorry about this

@user246821 ok, so I have to abandon this approach and try with "xml linq c#"

So the value of <Test>  isn't a string after all, it's a nested element?

If every single element name in your XML file (other than the root element name) could have some text prepended or appended, then LINQ to XML is probably the way to go.  Or you could try to create a custom XmlReader that strips the unwanted portions from the element names if you can create a general algorithm that cleans the element names of their unwanted portions.

Honestly this is a very unfortunate and unusual situation, XSD is based on element names so whatever app generated this file is going against the direction of the w3c XML standards.  Is there any chance you have an XY problem here?

@dbc I think you're right. There was no need to insist on obtaining data using the method I provided in the example.
I thought that if the names of the elements differ, it could be solved with some regex in the attributes in C#. But that's my lack of knowledge. Anyway, you helped me a lot, I wasted 2 days of work unnecessarily, but at least now I will take the right path. Thank you!

By the way, do you really have element names beginning with numbers like <11Test11>?  If so, your XML is malformed and you cannot read it with any XML parser, because XML disallows using digits for the first character in an element name.

@dbc No, that was an unfortunate example :)

You cannot make XmlSerializer map XML elements whose name matches some regular expression to a fixed .NET property because it is not implemented.  XmlSerializer is designed to serialize and deserialize C# objects to XML with some fixed XSD schema and XSD 1.0 schemas do not support using regular expressions in element names[1].
So, what are your options for a workaround?
Firstly, you could load your XML into a LINQ to XML XDocument and manually map that to your MainFile model.  To make that easier, first introduce the following extension methods:
public static partial class XNodeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<XElement> Elements(this XContainer container, Regex localNameRegex) => 
        container.Elements(localNameRegex, XNamespace.None);

    public static IEnumerable<XElement> Elements(this XContainer container, Regex localNameRegex, XNamespace @namespace)
        => container.Elements().Where(e => @namespace == e.Name.Namespace && localNameRegex.IsMatch(e.Name.LocalName));
}

And now you could do something like:
[XmlRoot("MainFile")]
public class FileAsXML
{
    public Test Test { get; set; }
}

public class Test 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HelloFriend { get; set; }
}

public static class FileAsXMLFactory
{
    const RegexOptions Options = RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Singleline;
    
    static XNamespace MainFileNamespace { get; } = "";
    
    public static FileAsXML Load(string fileName) => XDocument.Load(fileName).FromXDocument();

    public static FileAsXML FromXDocument(this XDocument doc) =>
        doc?.Root?.Name == MainFileNamespace + "MainFile"
        ? new FileAsXML
        {
            Test = doc.Root.Elements(new Regex("^.*Test[0-9]*$", Options), MainFileNamespace)
                .Select(test =>
                        new Test
                        {
                            HelloFriend = test.Elements(new Regex("^.*HelloFriend[0-9]*$", Options), MainFileNamespace).Select(h => h.Value).SingleOrDefault(),
                            Name = test.Elements(new Regex("^.*Name[0-9]*$", Options), MainFileNamespace).Select(n => n.Value).SingleOrDefault(),
                        }).SingleOrDefault(),
        }
        : throw new ArgumentException($"Unexpected root element \"{doc?.Root?.Name}\"");
}

Notes:

This looks to be the simplest approach if your data model doesn't have dozens of properties.

You might want to cache and reuse your Regex objects for performance.

The XML standard does not allow elements names to have a numeral as the first character:

[Definition: A Name is an Nmtoken with a restricted set of initial characters.] Disallowed initial characters for Names include digits, diacritics, the full stop and the hyphen.



Demo fiddle #1 here.
Secondly, if your XML file is huge and you don't want to load the entire thing into an XDocument, you could create some custom XmlReader decorator that renames elements on the fly as they are read.
To do that, define the following XmlReader subclasses:
public class ElementRenamingXmlReaderDecorator : XmlReaderDecorator
{
    readonly (Regex regex, string replacement) [] maps;
    string? cachedElementLocalName = null;

    public ElementRenamingXmlReaderDecorator(XmlReader baseReader, (Regex regex, string replacement) [] maps) : base(baseReader) => 
        this.maps = maps ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(maps));

    string GetRenamedLocalName(string name)
    {
        foreach (var map in maps)
            if (map.regex.IsMatch(name))
                return map.replacement;
        return name;
    }

    public override string LocalName => NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element 
        ? cachedElementLocalName ?? (cachedElementLocalName = NameTable.Add(GetRenamedLocalName(base.LocalName)))
        : base.LocalName;
    
    public override string Name =>
        NodeType switch
        {
            XmlNodeType.Element when Prefix.Length == 0 => LocalName,
            XmlNodeType.Element => NameTable.Add(string.Concat(Prefix, ":", LocalName)),
            _ => base.Name,
        };
        
    public override bool Read() { cachedElementLocalName = null; return base.Read(); }
    public override void Skip() { cachedElementLocalName = null; base.Skip(); }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) { cachedElementLocalName = null; base.Dispose(disposing); }
}

public class XmlReaderDecorator : XmlReader, IXmlLineInfo, IXmlNamespaceResolver
{
    private XmlReader? baseReader;

    public XmlReaderDecorator(XmlReader baseReader) => this.baseReader = baseReader ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(baseReader));

    protected XmlReader BaseReader => baseReader ?? throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().Name);

    public override XmlNodeType NodeType => BaseReader.NodeType;
    public override int Depth => BaseReader.Depth; 
    public override bool EOF => BaseReader.EOF;
    public override ReadState ReadState => BaseReader.ReadState;
    public override string Name => BaseReader.Name;
    public override string LocalName => BaseReader.LocalName;
    public override string NamespaceURI => BaseReader.NamespaceURI;
    public override string BaseURI => BaseReader.BaseURI; 
    public override string Prefix => BaseReader.Prefix; 
    public override bool HasValue => BaseReader.HasValue;
    public override string Value => BaseReader.Value; 
    public override Type ValueType => BaseReader.ValueType;
    public override bool IsEmptyElement => BaseReader.IsEmptyElement;
    public override bool IsDefault => BaseReader.IsDefault;
    public override char QuoteChar => BaseReader.QuoteChar;
    public override XmlSpace XmlSpace => BaseReader.XmlSpace;
    public override string XmlLang => BaseReader.XmlLang;
    public override bool HasAttributes => BaseReader.HasAttributes; 
    public override int AttributeCount => BaseReader.AttributeCount;
    public override bool CanResolveEntity => BaseReader.CanResolveEntity;
    public override XmlNameTable NameTable => BaseReader.NameTable;
    public override XmlReaderSettings? Settings => BaseReader.Settings;
    public override IXmlSchemaInfo? SchemaInfo => BaseReader.SchemaInfo;
    public override string this[int i] => BaseReader[i];
    public override string? this[string name] => BaseReader[name];
    public override string? this[string name, string? namespaceURI] => BaseReader[name, namespaceURI];
    public override string? GetAttribute(string name) => BaseReader.GetAttribute(name);
    public override string? GetAttribute(string name, string? namespaceURI) => BaseReader.GetAttribute(name, namespaceURI);
    public override string GetAttribute(int i) => BaseReader.GetAttribute(i);
    public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name) => BaseReader.MoveToAttribute(name);
    public override bool MoveToAttribute(string name, string? ns) => BaseReader.MoveToAttribute(name, ns);
    public override void MoveToAttribute(int i) => BaseReader.MoveToAttribute(i);
    public override bool MoveToFirstAttribute() => BaseReader.MoveToFirstAttribute();
    public override bool MoveToNextAttribute() => BaseReader.MoveToNextAttribute();
    public override bool MoveToElement() => BaseReader.MoveToElement();
    public override bool Read() => BaseReader.Read();
    public override void Skip() => BaseReader.Skip();
    public override void Close() => BaseReader.Close();
    public override string? LookupNamespace(string prefix) => BaseReader.LookupNamespace(prefix);
    public override void ResolveEntity() => BaseReader.ResolveEntity();
    public override bool ReadAttributeValue() => BaseReader.ReadAttributeValue();
    public virtual bool HasLineInfo() => BaseReader is IXmlLineInfo info ? info.HasLineInfo() : false;
    public virtual int LineNumber => BaseReader is IXmlLineInfo info ? info.LineNumber : 0;
    public virtual int LinePosition => BaseReader is IXmlLineInfo info ? info.LinePosition : 0;

    string? IXmlNamespaceResolver.LookupPrefix(string namespaceName) => BaseReader is IXmlNamespaceResolver resolver ? resolver.LookupPrefix(namespaceName) : null;
    IDictionary<string, string> IXmlNamespaceResolver.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope scope) => BaseReader is IXmlNamespaceResolver resolver ? resolver.GetNamespacesInScope(scope) : throw new NotImplementedException();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Do not throw an exception on multiple calls to dispose
        if (baseReader != null)
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.baseReader, null)?.Dispose();
    }
    
    // TODO : ASYNC
}

And now you could do:
public static class FileAsXMLFactory
{
    const RegexOptions Options = RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Singleline;
    
    static (Regex regex, string replacement) [] ElementNameMaps { get; } =
        [
            (new("^.*Test[0-9]*$", Options), "Test"),
            (new("^.*HelloFriend[0-9]*$", Options), "HelloFriend"),
            (new("^.*Name[0-9]*$", Options), "Name"),
        ];

    public static FileAsXML? Load(string fileName)
    {
        using var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName);
        return Load(reader);
    }

    public static FileAsXML? Load(XmlReader reader)
    {
        using var renamingReader = new ElementRenamingXmlReaderDecorator(reader, ElementNameMaps);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FileAsXML));
        return (FileAsXML?)serializer.Deserialize(renamingReader);
    }
}

Notes:

This approach won't work if you have a property in one part of your data model whose name needs to be replaced elsewhere, e.g. if you have the following in one type:
public string Name { get; set; }

And in some other type:
public string Name1 { get; set; }
public string Name2 { get; set; }



Demo fiddle #2 here.
Other alternatives include:

Using some XSLT transformation to fix your XML before deserializing.

Implement IXmlSerializable on every class in your data model, and populating everything manually using the incoming XmlReader.
Honestly I don't recommend it because this interface is very tricky to implement without introducing any bugs.

Asking the provider of your XML to modify their code to generate XML with fixed element names that can be validated against an XSD 1.0 Schema.



[1] For confirmation that this is not possible in XSD 1.0 see Can I use regular expressions in XML Schema element names?.  XSD 1.0 is the version supported by .NET.
